# Email Blast to multiple emails - W/h Rails .

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I am trying to create a feature where a user is able to dynamically email a group of people at once. In my demo app a user is able to create a event and anybody is able to book a pass to that event by entering in a email.

Currently I have a Event Model That belongs to one user.

And a booking model that belongs to the event.

In short I want the user to be able to email everyone who has a completed a booking for the Event.

I have no idea where to start so I was hoping to be guided in some sort of direction.

I know this is pretty broad but any help would be appreciated.